# Flutter: Cloud Message Not Delivered to Topic Subscriber

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I call `_firebaseMessaging.subscibeToTopic('topic-title');` to subscribe user to a topic on button click.

Some minutes after, the new topic showed at firebase cloud message console and i sent a message to the topic but I didn't received it. I don't understand why this is not working. I think there should be a option to add user's token to the `subscribeToTopic('topic-title', token)` or is the token automatically detected? Because am afraid the topic was only created with no token added.

Please i need help.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need user token for topic notification**

```
firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('newJobs'); //you are doing it correctly.
```

Now I think all you need is to minimize your running app while sending the notification because notification will not appear, if your app is on the resume state.

Comment: Thanks. I already got this when I read the README perfectly. I think i was wrong for expecting a notification when the app is on foreground. I got a notification when the app is on background. But do you have any fix on how to have the app to respond to data message when app is terminated?

Comment: Is there a way i could send notification to all user who subscribe to a topic except me who just did an action. Lets say i commented on a post. All other users who subscribed to that post to get a notification except me.